# Using an IQueryable in another IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I've an extension method, which returns an IQueryable, to get company products, I just want to use it in a IQueryable as a subquery,

```
public static class DBEntitiesCompanyExtensions {
   public static IQueryable<Product> GetCompanyProducts(this DBEntities db, int companyId)
   {
      return db.Products.Where(m => m.CompanyId == companyId);
   }
}
```

And this is how I call it,

```
using(var db = new DBEntities()) {
   var query = db.Companies.Select(m => new {
                CompanyName = m.Name,
                NumberOfProducts = db.GetCompanyProducts(m.CompanyId).Count()
   });    
}
```

I expected it to works beacuse my extension methods returns an IQueryable, so it could be used in a IQueryable, am I wrong?

This is what I get, Is that possible to make it work?

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebProject.Models.Company]
>   GetCompanyProducts(WebProject.Models.DBEntities, Int32)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: It can't understand how to transform `db.GetCompanyProducts(m.CompanyId)` into SQL, that is why it fails. You cant really encapsulate it to my knowledge. Plus `Count` will evaluate the queryable

Comment: It is simply not able to convert the `IQueryable` result to `Expression tree` mostly due to nested db context

Comment: @CallumLinington, yep it was the another problem, isn't that even possible to make it not evaluate until i finish my query, this is the part of my code so i've other conditions after that, evaluating query before those conditions would make it very slow performance.

Comment: To be honest with you - if my LINQ is getting complicated, I just write it in SQL in the code and fire it against the database. I stick to the principle that LINQ doesn't remove the need to know SQL

Comment: @CallumLinington, I'd better create sql views, thanks.

Comment: There is a benefit to writing SQL in your code - it gets version controlled, something which lacks in SQL. Just something to think about

Comment: concatenating SQL string according to conditions and requirements :(, that's what I don't want to meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not `IQueryable` inside `IQueryable`, because you can include subqueries just not the way you did.

In your example whole `Select` is represented as expression tree. In that expression tree there is something like :

```
CALL method DBEntitiesCompanyExtensions.GetCompanyProducts
```

Now EF should somehow traslate this into SQL SELECT statement. It cannot do that, because it cannot "look inside" `GetCompanyProducts` method and see what is going on there. Nor can it execute this method and do anything with it's result. The fact it returns `IQueryable` does not help and is not related.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IQueryable you should create an expression predicate and use inside the IQueryable object that is connected to the data source

the object looks like that:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate = x => x.Name == "Adi";

var data = await queryable.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
```