# Combine strings to List in Queryable

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In a Web API 2 project i have a controller that returns items from the database, like so;

```
[EnableQuery()]
public IQueryable<MyList> GetList()
{
    var items = from i in db.Items
        select new ItemsList()
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            Title = i.Title,
            cX = i.otherCollection.FirstOrDefault().cX,
            cY = i.otherCollection.FirstOrDefault().cY
        };
    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```

This works as expected.

But as you maybe can guess, otherCollection can contain x rows that relates to the current item. Currently i am only getting FirstOrDefault.
cX and cY is Lat and Lng coordinates.

I now need, to gather all coordinates from otherCollection, that relates to the current item, and return them as a combined list of LatLng, that i can then use, in a function, to find a center point (this function I have).

So i would like to do something like this:

```
var items = from i in db.Items
    select new ItemsList()
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        Title = i.Title,
        LatLng = GetCentralGeoCoordinate(i.otherCollection.cX.ToList() + i.otherCollection.cY.ToList()) //IList<GeoCoordinate> geoCoordinates
    };
return items.AsQueryable();
```

`i.otherCollection.cX` and `i.otherCollection.cY` are both string values.

How could i do that?

Comment: You want to combine `i.otherCollection.cX` with `i.otherCollection.cY`? If they are the same type, you can just use `.Concat`

Comment: What does "center point" mean? Show us a few examples.

Comment: @stybl "Centerpoint" just means, that instead of simply returning one latlng result, from FirstOrDefault(), i want to find the CenterPoint of the coordinates from the item (from otherCollection).
otherColection simply contains anywhere from 1 to 1000s of rows containing coordinates, attached to the single item.

So one item, can have 3000 rows in otherCollection, containing 3000 different coordinates. I have a function, that based on a list of LatLng, can find and return the center as a single LatLng value.

Comment: i understand your question is about lists, but you could (and maybe should) also consider that a function call in a Linq query often negates the main point of Linq for database queries, because it can't be expressed as SQL.  Math-wise, it seems implementing the calculation in pure Linq (without the function call) would be a good thing to try.  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201599/using-an-iqueryable-in-another-iqueryable) is a question that speaks to this conundrum.

Comment: Are you using EF?

Comment: @FilipCordas Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `GetCentralGeoCoordinate` as IQueryable. If you want to call this function you should first fetch the data to local memory, and then call this function for every element of your fetched sequence.

```
var result = db.Items
    .Select(item => new ItemsList()
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        ...
    })
    .AsEnumerable()       // bring your items to local memory
    .Select(item => GetCentralGeoCoordinate(...);
```

Now every GeoCoordinate has two properties: cX and cY. When finding the central coordinate you need to know which cx belongs to which cy. You want something like this:

```
var coordinates = (4, 10) (8, 15) (3, 7) ...
```

and not

```
var xCoordintate = 4, 8, 3, ...
var yCoordinates = 10, 15, 7, ...
```

Your query would be:

```
var items = db.Items
select (item => new ItemsList()
{
    Id = item.Id,
    Title = item.Title,
    Coordinates = item.OtherCollection
        .Select(otherCollectionItem => new Coordinate()
        {
            Cx = otherCollectionItem.Cx,
            Cy = otherCollectionItem.Cy,
        })
        .ToList(),
}
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(fetchedItem => GetCentralGeoCoordinate(fetchedItem.Coordinate));
```

The `Coordinate` class is a simple class with a cX and a cY. Similar to `System.Drawing.Point`

Your function to calculate the central Coordinate will take a sequence of Coordinates and returns the one and only central Coordinate (and maybe null if there is no central Coordinate)

```
Coordinate GetCentralGeoCoordinate(IEnumerable<Coordinate> coordinates)
{
    foreach (Coordinate coordinate in Coordinates)
    {
        ... // do something with the coordinate
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer! I am trying to implement your solution, but I am getting an error at ".AsEnumerable()" - 'ItemsList does not contain a definition for AsEnumerable' ?

Comment: FWIW, you can **always** use this technique to implement something in LINQ that's too cumbersome/difficult to be turned directly into a single SQL query.  But, this should NOT be used too much, as it moves all the work from the database into the C# application, which defeats the main purpose (performance-wise) of IQueryables.in the first place.

Comment: Nevermind - it was just a missing ), that was causing the error.