# Linq, why splitting query into separate method doesn't run

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am aware this isn't a real example. We came across it by accident and then wondered why, even though it's wrong, it doesn't work

```
{
    var links = 
        from z in (
            await (
                from x in employees

                // Version 1
                let y = LinqFromSeparateMethod(employees).ToArray()


                // Version 2
                /*
                    let y = (from z in employees
                    from y in z.EmployeeAddressLink
                    select y).ToArray()
                */

                select new
                {
                   y,
                   x
                }
            ).ToArrayAsync()
        )
        select(
            z.y.ToArray()
        );
}

private IQueryable<EmployeeAddressLink> LinqFromSeparateMethod(IQueryable<Employee> employees)
{
    return from x in employees 
           from y in x.EmployeeAddressLink
           select y;
}
```

Here we have a very simple database structure, from an employee table to an employeeaddresslink table

We have a block of code that can either be embedded directly within the linq query or can be returned as an IQueryable from a method

We call ToArray on the block in both cases

- If its embedded directly in the linq then it runs
- If we use the method version then we get an error "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed"

Given that the method returns an IQueryable shouldn't these be identical?

Just to add, if the .ToArray() section is taken off the method then both the method and the equivalent block run without errors

Comment: What if the code was running completely synchronously, would that make a difference?

Comment: Good question. I just checked, it still has the same error

Comment: I would check it in sharplab.io if they are really identical or not.

Comment: I don't think LINQ supports calling a custom method inside it like this, because you can do whatever you want inside a function, but you're restricted by LINQ syntax if you're using it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201599/using-an-iqueryable-in-another-iqueryable

Comment: Im digging for any spec or question stating on LinQ expression building with sub method like this.

Comment: I've added a tag for entity framework core. Apologies if it makes a difference. As I haven't worked with the previous version so it didn't occur to me to add that

Comment: Can you try using `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToArrayAsync()`?

Comment: I removed all the async stuff completely, same error